# how to use pointer to pointer to slice string

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, memory-management

I read about pointer to pointers on [tutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_to_pointer.htm).

I had a little test myself. I want to slice a string by space so that every words (include the punctuation) are treated as a token and the tokens are returned line by line.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** split(const char* s)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char** word = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    * word = malloc(strlen(s)+1);

    while (*s != '\0') {
        if (*s == ' ') {
            i++;
        } else {
            word[i][j] = *s;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        s++;
    }

    return word;
    //free(word);  //with or without this i get the same outcome.
}

int main(void)
{
    char** words = split("He said 'hello' to me!");
    int i = 0;
    while (words[i] != NULL) {
        puts(words[i]);
        free(words[i]);
        i += 1;
    }
    free(words);
}
```

It compiles but when I run on terminal I get segmentation fault. I added a `printf` in my if statement, it prints every letter.

I also used `valgrind`, but I cannot understand what it is saying.

expected output:

```
He
said
'hello'
to
me!
```

Comment: Area secured by malloc is incorrect.

Comment: Do i have to allocate exactly same size of memory as the tokens?

Comment: @chrisgjh you could, but you don't have. I remember when doing the same as you, I would be taught first to use a little bit memory more, and by the time I understood how this worked, I was then able to do the same with the exact same size of memory as the tokens! ;)

Comment: @chrisgjh The sample was posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I will comment on your attempt:

Here:

```
return word;
free(word);
```

free won't be executed! You see anything that lies *after* the `return` statement, doesn't execute!

Moreover, the space allocated dynamically with `malloc()` is wrong, check about how we do that in my [2D dynamic array](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/), or/and read the example below.

You see, without having allocated the sufficient, you were accessing out of bound memory, which would cause **Undefined Behavior**, but you are lucky to get a segmentation fault, which alerted you! :)

I won't debug your code, since it's a wonderful chance to practice, but if you want ask more.

Here is how I would do it, it's a simpler approach, but if you get that, then you will be able to work on your own attempt! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// We return the pointer
char **get(int N, int M) // Allocate the array */
{
    // TODO: Check if allocation succeeded. (check for NULL pointer)
    int i;
    char** table;
    table = malloc(N*sizeof(char *));
    for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
        table[i] = malloc( M*sizeof(char) );
    return table;
}

void free2Darray(char** p, int N) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
        free(p[i]);
    free(p);
}

void zeroFill(char** p, int N, int M) {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
        for(j = 0 ; j < M ; j++)
            p[i][j] = 0;
}

void print(char** p, int N, int M) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
        if(strlen(p[i]) != 0)
            printf("array[%d] = %s\n", i, p[i]);
}

void split(const char* s, char** words) {
    int i = 0, word_idx = 0, char_idx = 0;
    while(s[i] != '\0') {
        if(s[i] != ' ') {
            words[word_idx][char_idx++] = s[i];
        } else {
            word_idx++;
            char_idx = 0;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char** words = get(10, 15); // 10 words, 14 chars max (+1 for n$
    zeroFill(words, 10, 15);

    split("He said 'hello' to me!", words);
    print(words, 10, 15);

    free2Darray(words, 10);
    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ nano main.c
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
array[0] = He
array[1] = said
array[2] = 'hello'
array[3] = to
array[4] = me!
```

The explanation:

1. I assume a sentence will have at most 10 words, and every word will
   be at most 14 characters long (+1 for the NULL-terminator).
2. Allocate dynamically a 2D array, of 10 rows and 15 columns.
3. Initialize all of its elements to zero. I did so just to make sure
   the words are NULL terminated. I could of course skip that step and
   insert the NULL terminator manually at the exact position in
   `split()`.
4. Split the string in tokens.
5. Print the words.
6. Free the dynamically allocated memory of the 2D array.

Now, let me explain a bit more the `split()` function:

Actually your attempt was pretty good, so you probably know already what I am doing:

1. I loop over the string, until I meet the NULL terminator.
2. As long as I don't meet the whitespace, I insert the current
   character in the current word. `word_idx` helps me remember which
   word I am filling up now, and which character of that word with
   `char_idx`.
3. When I meet the whitespace (the `else` case), I have to advance to
   the next word (no need to NULL-terminate the string I filled up
   before, since I have zero initialized my 2D array), by incrementing
   `word_idx` by 1. I also set `char_idx` to 0, so that I can start
   filling up the new word from position 0.

Answer (score 1):

`split` fix like this.

```
char **split(const char *s){
    int i = 0, j;
    int len = strlen(s);
    len += (len & 1);//+1 if len is odd
    char **word = malloc((len / 2 + 1) * sizeof(*word));//+1 for NULL

    while (*s) {
        while(*s == ' ')
            ++s;//skip spaces
        if(!*s)
            break;
        for(len = 0; s[len] && s[len] != ' '; ++len)
            ;
        word[i] = malloc(len + 1);
        for(j = 0; j < len; ++j)
            word[i][j] = *s++;
        word[i++][j] = '\0';
    }
    word[i] = NULL;
    return word;
}
```

Comment: The check return value  of `malloc` is omitted.